# Getting the caller ID in Android 9

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-9.0-pie, caller-id

I have been using the following code in a `BroadcastReceiver` to get
the caller ID of incoming calls:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context aContext, Intent aIntent) {
   String action = aIntent.getAction();

   if (action==null) return;
   if (!action.equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) return;

   String curState = aIntent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

   if ((TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(curState))
      &&(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(oldState)))){
      String incNumber = aIntent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

      // do something here
   }
   oldState=curState;
}
```

Unfortunately this has stopped working in Android 9.0 (API 28). More specifically,
`aIntent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)` always returns null. In android versions<=API 27 everything works correctly

I have also added the `READ_PHONE_STATE` and `READ_CALL_LOG` permissions in the manifest file.

Any ideas? Anybody else experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Sir post the logcat errors

Comment: Hi, there are no logcat errors. The code seams to execute normally but the incNumber variable always contains null.

Comment: For me it's always null on Android9. Anyone?

Comment: Did you get any solution? I have aske for both permission at runtime. Still incomingNumber is null.

Comment: @GreenROBO - sorry for the delayed response - see answer below (and the comments below the answer...).

Answer (score 30):

I found the answer to my question:

First, in `Android 9`, you have to explicitly ask for both the `READ_PHONE_STATE` and the `READ_CALL_LOG` permissions at run time. In previous Android versions you only had to ask for the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. Both of them have to be asked at run time.

Second, if both of the above permissions have been given, the `onReceive` method is called twice (!!). The first time the intent is "empty" (`EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` is null). The second time the intent is normally populated as it should. This is documented in the [TelephonyManager Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED).

Comment: Is your broadcast receiver call when application is closed ?? I am facing this issue. Please post your whole receiver.

Comment: Yes, the receiver was called.
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/providing-safe-and-secure-experience.html

Comment: Sorry, the previous comment was posted without having finished it. I wanted to bring to your attention the new google policy, effective January 9, 2019, which restricts the use of the use of the READ_CALL_LOG permission (see the link in the previous comment).

Comment: As @haris wrote, since January 9, 2019 you cant ask for READ_CALL_LOG if your application is not default dialler app. How can I get caller id without this permission on api 28 and above?

Comment: Read call logs permission is restrict by google developer console. You can not request request this permission.You need to fill up the form for access the permission and if they agree than only you can use this permission

Comment: For me it's always null on Android9. Anyone?

Comment: @spajdo i wonder how this app is doing it then :  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.triputiapps.nameannouncer, they are not default dialer

Comment: @j2emanue I don't know. Maybe he got exception, or his application will not work on Android 9 or higher. I don't have Android 9 yet, but someone can test it.

Comment: Did you get any solution? I have aske for both permission at runtime. Still incomingNumber is null.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it is working. I got an error on first onReceive call, I put condition to execute the next line only if incoming number is not null, then automatically called onReceive call again, fortunately, got the incoming number ..

Comment: @haris can you publish this application in google play store?
If so please  help me to publish this application. When i add this read call log permission they don't publish my app.

Comment: @pavel, My app has been also removed from google play store (It had been there form almost 10 years, with many users :-( ). I distribute it now as an apk from my website.

Comment: can you tell me the full process about your distribution process.

Comment: not getting the phone_state broadcast when app is closed on android 9. any suggestions !!!

Answer (score 4):

Add `READ_CALL_LOG` permission in manifest as below :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Then

Apps -> Your App -> Permissions -> Grant Call Logs Permission

Your should get phone number now, after the second time your `receiver` is called