# Incoming number is null after ending the call in android PIE 9

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I have been working on this problem since weeks. I am making an app which picks the incoming number and shows it in a dialog box after the call is ended. Everything is working fine below android PIE 9.0. The number is always null in android PIE. I have given all permissions including `READ_CALL_LOGS` but same problem. The incoming number is null. So please anyone help me...

**Here is my manifest file :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.softixtechnologies.phonemanager">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/calllogo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:persistent="true"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/calllogo"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".activities.CallLogEntryActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.CallLogsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.IgnoredNumbersActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.IContactsActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.SplashActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".activities.CategoryPhoneActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LogsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_logs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CategoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_category"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".callhelpers.CallReciever"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

**Here is my code** :

```
    public class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    private static Date callStartTime;
    private static boolean isIncoming;
    private static String savedNumber;
    public String phoneNr ;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper ;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);


    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
                savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
            } else {
                String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

                int state = 0;
                if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
                } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
                } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                    state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
                }
                onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
            }
    }

    protected void onIncomingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}

    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end){}

    protected void onMissedCall(final Context ctx, final String number, Date start){}

    public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number){
            if (lastState == state) {
                return;
            }
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    isIncoming = true;
                    callStartTime = new Date();
                    savedNumber = number;

                    onIncomingCallStarted(context, number, callStartTime);
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    if (lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                        isIncoming = false;
                        callStartTime = new Date();
                        onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                    }
                    break;

                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

                    if (lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                            onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
                    } else if (isIncoming) {

                        onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                    } else {
                        onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
                    }
                    break;
            }
            lastState = state;
    }
    public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(number));
        String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
        Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                return true;
            }
        } finally {
            if (cur != null)
                cur.close();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Share you permission code from Manifest.

Comment: I have added my manifest

Comment: Check this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009874/getting-the-caller-id-in-android-9

Comment: I didn't understand How can I call the receiver twice?

Comment: Because it's not mentioned with any details in Documentation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two different "types" of phone state receivers, receivers that have `Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG` permission and receivers that don't.

If a receiver doesn't have the `Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG` permission, it will be called for all state changed once, without the `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` extra.

If a receiver does have that above permission, like in your case, it will be called for every state changed twice, one without the `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` permission, and another time with it.

Since you have this code:

```
if (lastState == state) {
    return;
}
```

in your `onCallStateChanged` method, you're basically skipping the second call, and thus losing the `EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER` info.

If you're sure you have the `READ_CALL_LOG` permission, you can try skipping the duplicated receiver call without that extra completely (however note that there's a difference between getting a "null" value for that extra which means a private number call, and not getting that extra at all), like so:

```
String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
if (!intent.getExtras().containsKey(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)) {
    Log.i("Call receiver", "skipping intent=" + intent + ", extras=" + intent.getExtras() + " - no number was supplied");
    return;
}
String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```

See the official docs at: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED

Answer (score 0):

In Android 9, the number is included in intent extras under key `incoming_number`